# how to create "ONLY STATUS BAR NOTIFICATION like Alarm clock, battery,3g in android without expandable drawer

Tags: android

I dont drawer type notification.. i only want only an icon as notification..plzz help guyss

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible from an Android SDK application, sorry.